# Quickest way to reduce ~400 images to .05% of original size

Tags: images, batch

I have around 400 images that are taken from a 8 megapixel camera. I want to reduce the image size to around 4k pixels. What is the fastest way to do this, I have access to both windows and linux systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really only 4k pixels? Anyway, using [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) you can run:

```
gm mogrify -output-directory 4k -resize 52x78 *.jpg
```

Or, if you prefer, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) has pretty much the same syntax.

Answer (score 5):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/).  Does it all and it's free.

Comment: Yes, Irfanview would be my choice for this job on Windows machine. The gui interface to specify this batch job makes its slightly easier than using command line.

Comment: can you batch this? I've got 400 images.

Comment: Ya, that's what's great about Irfanview.  Has a batch processing mode with a ton of options.  In fact, batch processing is really all I use it for.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows I've always used [`nconvert`](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert.html):

```
nconvert -thumb 78 78 -o $\thumb\% *.jpg
```

XnView (on the same page) can do the same.

Comment: How do you use that @Joey?

Comment: Might be that I got the syntax for `-o` slightly wrong; just didn't have a directory of images to test with.